# How can I use "Arial" in math mode with Beamer?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

In my `beamer`, I applied "`\setmainfont{Arial}`" and "`\setsansfont{Arial}`" to set the main font as Arial, and I would like to apply the same or a similar font in the math mode. I write my LaTeK code as below, thanks to [Tilde in math mode using helvetica](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130328/tilde-in-math-mode-using-helvetica).

However, there are many errors when running the code even if the pdf file can be still generated.

[image]

and **the "`\partical`" cannot be displayed**.

[image]

Shall I use another kind of font? I just want to use a math font that looks like Arial and also has an effect on the Greek alphabet like "`\alpha`" or "`\varepsilon`".

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\ifPDFTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setsansfont{Arial}
%% Change this line to change the math symbols:
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
%% Set various (but not all) Unicode tilde symbols:
\setmathfont[range={"007E,"02DC,"02F7,"0303,"0330,"0334,"033F,"034A,"0360}]{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
%% Set the math alphabets:
\setmathfont[range=up]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Arial Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Arial Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Arial Bold Italic}

\newcommand*{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*{\N}{\mathrm{N}}

\begin{decument}
    \begin{frame}

    The equations were presented as
    \begin{align}
        &y_{i} = \beta_{1}x_{i, 1} + \beta_{2}\sin(x_{i, 2}) + \beta_{3}\ln(x_{i, 3}) + \varepsilon_{i} \quad \Phi(x) = 1-\Phi(-x) \\
        &\dfrac{\dif y}{\dif x} = e^{x} \quad \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=0} = t \quad \oint_{|C|=1} f(z) \dif z = 2\pi i \times \left\lbrace \mathrm{res}[f(z), i] \right\rbrace \\
        &x_{n} \iid \N(0, 1) \quad x^{2}_{n} \iid \chi^{2}(1) \quad \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_{n} \iid \chi^{2}(N) \\
        &\iint_{R} g(x,y)\dif x\dif y= \int_{0}^{1}\dif x \int_{0}^{1}g(x,y)\dif y \quad \lim\limits_{\rho \to 0}h(\rho) = 0\left( \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \right) \\
        & x =\begin{cases}
            1, \mathcal{H}_{0}\\
            0, \mathcal{H}_{1} 
        \end{cases}\; (2\pi L(x;\mu,\sigma^{2}) = \sigma^{2})^{-\frac{N}{2}}\exp\left\lbrace -\dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_{n} - \mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right\rbrace 
    \end{align}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document not compile: fix typo `\begin{decument}` and there are double `\setsansfont{Arial}` and many mix of the packages. And do you want use `helvet` with `arial` togheter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `\usepackage{sansmath}`and not only `\sfmath` to set the font for all the document.

Please, check this thread for a full discussion about Math font setting: [Typeset mathematical symbols also in sans serif font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/typeset-mathematical-symbols-also-in-sans-serif-font)

I hope it helps.